# Convert hours and minute to millisecond using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, time, highcharts

I have `Hours:Minute` format of time as `string` type. To display them in highchart as a time I need to convert this `string` into milliseconds.
For example: `34:26` (34 hours and 26 minutes) milliseconds are `124000000`
How can i convert it to milliseconds using any of `jquery` or `javascript` function?

Comment: You can simply create a Javascript function that convert it to milliseconds. function(var hours, var minutes, var seconds){ return hours * 3600000 + minutes * 60000 + seconds * 1000; }

Comment: Have a look at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds

Answer (score 17):

Try this code:

```
const toMilliseconds = (hrs,min,sec) => (hrs*60*60+min*60+sec)*1000;

console.log(toMilliseconds(34, 26, 0)); // --> 123960000ms
```

Comment: It should be (+hrs * 60 * 60 + +min * 60 + +sec)*1000;

Answer (score 9):

This is simple.

```
var time = "34:26";
var timeParts = time.split(":");
console.log((+timeParts[0] * (60000 * 60)) + (+timeParts[1] * 60000));
```

Answer (score 9):

Arrow functions + hoisting variation with ES2015:

```
// Function
const milliseconds = (h, m, s) => ((h*60*60+m*60+s)*1000);

// Usage
const result = milliseconds(24, 36, 0);

// Contextual usage
const time = "34:26";
const timeParts = time.split(":");
const result = milliseconds(timeParts[0], timeParts[1], 0);
console.log(result);
```

This way you can componetize or make it service

Comment: Shorter using the spread operator ... :

`const milliseconds = (h, m, s = 0) => (h*60*60+m*60+s)*1000;
const time = "34:26";
const result = milliseconds(...time.split(':'));`